# Consuming a PHP SOAP WebService with ASP.NET

Tags: .net, php, asp.net, soap, wsdl

I'm having some major issues trying to consume my PHP SOAP webservice using ASP.NET. The webservice in question is based on the PHP SOAP extension and is descibed by the following WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<definitions name="MyServices"
  targetNamespace="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services"
  xmlns:tns="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsd1="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <complexType name="ServiceType">
            <all>
                <element name="id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <element name="cost" type="xsd:float" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="ArrayOfServiceType">
            <all>
                <element name="Services" type="ServiceType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>


<message name="getServicesRequest">
    <part name="postcode" type="xsd:string" />
</message>

<message name="getServicesResponse">
  <part name="Result" type="xsd1:ArrayOfServiceType"/>
</message>

<portType name="ServicesPortType">
  <operation name="getServices">
    <input message="tns:getServicesRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:getServicesResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="ServicesBinding" type="tns:ServicesPortType">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="getServices">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services/getServices" />
    <input>
      <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:my:services" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:my:services" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>

<service name="MyServices">
  <port name="ServicesPort" binding="tns:ServicesBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

I can successfully generate a proxy class from this WSDL in Visual Studio, but upon trying to invoke the getServices method I am presented with an exception:

**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Procedure 'string' not present**

After inspecting the raw post data at the SOAP server end, my PHP SOAP client is making requests like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <postcode xsi:type="xsd:string">ln4 4nq</postcode>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Whereas the .Net proxy class is doing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services" 
    xmlns:types="http://mydomain.com/api/soap/v11/services/encodedTypes" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <xsd:string xsi:type="xsd:string">LN4 4NQ</xsd:string>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can only assume the difference in the way the postcode parameter is being sent is where the problem lies, but as primarily a PHP developer I'm at a loss as to what's occuring here. I have a feeling I'm simply missing something vital in my WSDL as I've seen countless examples of 'Consuming PHP SOAP WebServices with .Net' which appear to suggest that it 'just works'.

Any suggestion as to where i've slipped up here would be greatly appreciated. I've currently spent almost an entire day on this now ;-)

Thanks in advance,

Jamie

Comment: It's easy to slip up... on SOAP :-D

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to make an answer instead of a comment by I don't have enough reputation for that yet...

You should try to test your webservice with SOAP-UI (they have a free version), so you'll know if the problem is client side or server side.

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL has errors, therefore most probably the proxy class is corrupt. So is the request. 
WSDL is very complex to do right unless you use a good WSDL editor. I would sugget Eclipse WSDL editor (http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor)
(1) The {max occurs} of an element in an 'all' model group must be 0 or 1. The value '-1' for element 'Services' is invalid.
(2) Error resolving component 'ServiceType'. It was detected that 'ServiceType' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document